# MySql Local Database

Tags: java, mysql, jar

I have made an application that connects to my local MySql Database through java code and inserts and reads data. I need to package the application up in a jar and send it to a friend for his use. I have now run into the problem of how I will get that local database in that jar . How could I be able to allow access to my local db on another computer? Is it possible to be able to get an instance of that db over to his pc? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).  It will dump your entire database and data into a file.  You can then send that file to your friend and have them run it to build the database and insert the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your DB to a file (using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)). Your friend would have to install mysql on his/her computer and then initialize the DB with your dump file.